# How to prevent Lambda expressions defined in a Java agent break the application it is attached to?

Tags: java, byte-buddy, javaagents, java-security-manager

If I declare this advice in my agent:

```java
public static class SequenceAdvice {
    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    static void enter(@Advice.This Object thiz, 
                      @Advice.Origin Method method, 
                      @Advice.AllArguments Object... args) {
        StackWalker walker = 
            StackWalker.getInstance(RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE);

        walker.forEach(sf -> 
            System.out.println(sf.getClassName() + "." + sf.getMethodName())
        );
    }
}
```

as `javac` compiles the lambda expression into a private method (at least in OpenJDK 11):

```java
public class SequenceAgent$SequenceAdvice {
  ...
  private static void lambda$enter$0(java.lang.StackWalker$StackFrame);
  ...
}
```

when the agent is attached to a program and the program is executed, it causes the program to crash:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: 
  class DemoController tried to access private method
    SequenceAgent$SequenceAdvice.lambda$enter$0(
       Ljava/lang/StackWalker$StackFrame;)V 
         (DemoController and SequenceAgent$SequenceAdvice 
          are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at DemoController.getDemos(DemoController.java)
    at DemoMain.main(DemoMain.java:13)
```

Ideally I prefer not to use objects instead of lambda expressions to workaround this:

```
public static class SequenceAdvice {

    public static Consumer<StackWalker.StackFrame> SF_CONSUMER = 
        new Consumer<>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(StackWalker.StackFrame sf) {
                System.out.println(sf.getClassName() + "." + sf.getMethodName());
            }
    };

    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    static void enter(@Advice.This Object thiz, 
                      @Advice.Origin Method method, 
                      @Advice.AllArguments Object... args) {
        StackWalker walker = StackWalker.getInstance(RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE);

        walker.forEach(SF_CONSUMER);
    }
}
```

A custom permissive security policy does not seem to resolve this error:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Is there a way to temporarily disable this category of security checks (e.g. *"access to private method"*)?

Comment: Could you use a method reference instead? / I don't think anything relevant here is going through `AccessController`, so permissions don't matter. It's bytecode rules that have been broken, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use lambda expressions from an advice. The lambda expression will be a part of the advice class that is not exposed to the target class. Instead, you will need to define a utility class that defines the lambda expressions code in public methods and reference those methods as method references.

You must then either:

1. add this class to the bootstrap class loader via `Instrumentation`.
2. add this class to the class loader of the instrumented class via Byte Buddy's `Injector`.

This way, the references are available to the instrumented class and can be executed.